# How to make my shell script check every folder in a directory for a word and then rank the outputs?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a folder `reviews_folder` that contains lots of files, such as `hotel_217616.dat`. I have written a script `countreviews.sh` to check the number of times the word "Author" appears in each file and then print the number out for each respective file. Here is my script:

```
grep -r "<Author>" "#1"
```

I cannot write `reviews_folder` in the shell code, it must take it as an argument in the command line, hence `#1`. The number of time my word appears in each file must then be ranked from highest to lowest, for example

```
-- run script --
49
23
17
```

However, when I run my script it says `"#1: No such file or directory"`; why isn't it replacing `#1` with `reviews_folder` when I type:

```
./countreviews.sh reviews_folder
```

My `countreviews.sh` is sitting in the same directory as my `reviews_folder`, which contains the files I will be checking if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the positional parameter is `$1` and not `#1`.

Secondly, your script doesn't really "count the number of time the word `Author` appears"; it looks literally for `<Author>`, including the angle brackets.

I assume you wanted word boundaries, as in `\<Author\>`.

`grep -r` just lists all matching lines, prepended by filenames. You want only the count, and sorted. To do this, you can do

```
grep -rwch 'Author'
```

- `-w` searches for word matches
- `-c` returns a match count per file
- `-h` suppresses writing the file name

And to sort the output, you pipe it to `sort`:

```
grep -rwch 'Author' | sort -nr
```

`-n` is for "numerical sort", and `-r` for "reverse", so the largest number is first.

Notice how this *still* only counts how many *lines* matched "Author"; if there is a line with five matches, it is counted only as one by `grep -c`.

To properly count every single occurrence, you could to this:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -wo "Author" {} | wc -l' \; | sort -nr
```

- `find . -type f` finds recursively all files.
- `-exec` executes a command for each file found. Because we use a pipe in that command, we have to spawn a subshell with `bash -c`.
- `grep -wo "Author" {} | wc -l` finds every match of `Author` and prints it on a separate line; `wc -l` then counts the lines.
- After this happened for all files, `sort -nr` again sorts the results.

Comment: Thanks man you rock, your last example was what I was after and thanks for explaining what each part does

Answer (score 1):

ITYM `$1`, not `#1`

..........................................

Comment: Fixed it, how could I then rank my outputs? for example my output for one of my files is foldername/filename/:"No. of times"

Comment: That is a completely different question to what you asked in your question (`when I run my script it says "#1: No such file or directory", why isn't it replacing #1 with reviews_folder `) so accept an answer to this one and post a new question.